# Plotting vector fields with two different methods (quiver / streamplot) resulting in plots that don't match - Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some vector flows in Python, using **Matplotlib** and I'm having some trouble...

I'm trying to compare two methods, the [**quiver**](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=quiver) and the [**streamplot()**](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=streamplot). I've already read both documentations, but I wasn't able to get the same results for both.

I'm plotting the vectors with these two methods:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def plot_quiver(x_dim, y_dim, steps, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, file_path):
    plt.figure()

    x, y = numpy.mgrid[-x_dim/2:x_dim/2:steps*1j, -y_dim/2:y_dim/2:steps*1j]

    plt.quiver(x, y, vector_field_x, vector_field_y)

    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()


def plot_streamlines(file_path, x_dim, y_dim, steps, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, scalar_field=None):
    plt.figure()

    y, x = numpy.mgrid[-x_dim/2:x_dim/2:steps*1j, -y_dim/2:y_dim/2:steps*1j]

    plt.figure()

    if scalar_field is not None:
        cs = plt.contour(x, y, scalar_field, extent=[-x_dim/2.0, x_dim/2.0, -y_dim/2.0, y_dim/2.0])
        plt.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)

    # x, y : 1d arrays, an evenly spaced grid.
    # u, v : 2d arrays
    # x and y-velocities. Number of rows should match length of y, and the number of columns should match x.
    plt.streamplot(x, y, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)

    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

However, I just don't know how to get both plots "equal".

The first method plots this image (which is what I was expecting):

[image]

And the second one gives me this:

[image]

I don't know what I have to do so they match. I tried every possible combination and got nothing...

And I really need both visualizations.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You transpose `x, y` -> `y, x` on the second line of `plot_streamlines`.

Comment: But this seems to be required by the stream plot documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964856/plotting-streamlines-with-matplotlib-python/23964989?noredirect=1#comment36922376_23964989

Comment: You should simplify your example code add much as possible